# Issue with accented characters in SQLiteStudio

Tags: sqlite, encoding

I downloaded a [SQLite 3 dump of Northwind](http://bit.ly/norwind), and opened it in [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/). Accented characters aren't displayed nicely. How to solve the issue? I suspect some encoding issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> SELECT hex(CompanyName) FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = 'BOLID';
42F36C69646F20436F6D696461732070726570617261646173
```

This is not valid UTF-8.

That database was not created correctly.

If you know what the characters are supposed to be, you could manually fix them:

```
UPDATE Customers SET CompanyName = replace(CompanyName, x'F3', 'ó');
```

(You'd have to repeat this for all columns and all wrong characters.)